# How to initialise a AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm very new to iOS/Swift development. I'm trying to implement user signup/signin using **AWS Cognito**. After initialising the SDK with a default configuration I do:

```
let pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool(forKey: "UserPool")
```

[followed by]

```
pool.signUp(...)
```

to register a user.

I need to pass and array of `AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType` to the signUp method, but I'm unable to initialise objects of this type.

```
var first_name = AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType(
                                 dictionary: ["given_name": "rob"])
```

results in the following **Error:**

```
2016-07-10 08:48:43.025 Demo1[4199:111322] -
         [AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType initWithDictionary:]: 
         unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fee54a6ede0
```

Comment: I finally figured out how to initialise AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType in Swift!    

let first_name = AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType()
first_name.name = "given_name"
first_name.value = "rob"

Answer (score 0):

I Belive you should do like this, create an Array of AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType, then create a bunch of objects of that type, assign the 'name' then the 'value' as I did below. Then you can use that object 'attributes' in your pool.signup

```
    var attributes = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType]()
    let name = AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType()
    let email = AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType()
    let gender = AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType()
    let birthdate = AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType()
    let username = AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType()

    let myFormatter = DateFormatter()
    myFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

    name?.name = "name"
    email?.name = "email"
    gender?.name = "gender" //implementar genero ainda
    birthdate?.name = "birthdate"
    sobrenome?.name = "family_name"
    username?.name = "preferred_username"


    let birthdateNsDate:Date = birthdateField.date as Date
    birthdate?.value = myFormatter.string(from: birthdateNsDate)
    name?.value = nameTextField.text!
    email?.value = emailTextField.text!


    attributes.append(name!)
    attributes.append(email!)
    attributes.append(gender!)
    attributes.append(birthdate!)
    attributes.append(sobrenome!)
    attributes.append(username!)
```

Answer (score 0):

A single instance:

e.g.,

```
AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType(name: "key", value: "string")
```

An array as a parameter in a function call:

```
awsUserPool.currentUser()?.update([
    AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType(name: "key0", value: string0),
    AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType(name: "key1", value: string1)
])
```

Values need to be converted to a String. E.g.,

```
    AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType(name: "key", value: "\(number)")
```

Comment: Carl, your sample code: AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType(name: "key", value: number) returns an error. It seems that the AWS attribute always wants a string value - even if the custom attribute is stored as a number in Cognito. Do you agree?

Comment: @SteveW. you're right! In my own code, I'd only used Strings but I got carried away in writing up my answer. I've made the correction. This type of API from AWS appears to be dropped by Amazon. AWSCognitoSync, for example, is also limited to String values and has recently been deprecated and replaced by AWSAppSync - a far more involving API.

Answer (score 0):

Following snippet demonstrates how to use

```
AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType * phone = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType new];
phone.name = @"phone_number";
//phone number must be prefixed by country code
phone.value = @"+15555555555";
AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType * email = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType new];
email.name = @"email";
email.value = @"email@mydomain.com";

//sign up the user
[[pool signUp:@"username" password:@"password" userAttributes:@[email,phone] validationData:nil] continueWithBlock:^id _Nullable(AWSTask<AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolSignUpResponse *> * _Nonnull task) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if(task.error){
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:task.error.userInfo[@"__type"]
                                        message:task.error.userInfo[@"message"]
                                       delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        }else {
            AWSCognitoIdentityUserPoolSignUpResponse * response = task.result;
            if(!response.userConfirmed){
                //need to confirm user using user.confirmUser:
            }
        }});
    return nil;
}];
```

Following link describes usage of User Pools with the iOS SDK:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-ios-sdk.html